# Can I make latex ignore some definitions or replace them with kind of a pre-processor define

Tags: tikz-arrows

I write a document on several machines. One of them has Ubuntu 14.04 installed with a kind of dated installation of TexLive. The others have Ubuntu 14.10 and Arch Linux.

In my document I use the **arrows.meta** library. Now I am stuck with a document that does not compile on one of my machines (the 14.04 one).

Is there a way, I can make latex to ignore all the problematic definitions. What I would like to have is something (perhaps a few lines of code to comment in and out) to enable and disable the newer features of TikZ without changing the source files of the actual images? Right now its 9 images using the arrows.meta tips and this number might grow. So, changing the image's source is not the way to go.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % input encoding
\usepackage{lmodern}            % fonts

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}      % provides TikZ


\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

%\newcommand{\Stealth}{\stealth}    % does not work

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-Stealth] (0,0) to (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: upgrade TikZ to 3.0.0?

Comment: Upgrade TeXLive? It is incredibly straightforward.

Comment: You could use `\IfFileExists...` to test for whether there is an `arrows.meta` library. (You'll need the proper file name.) Then define a style conditionally and load the appropriate library. But only even consider this if you have no other option which would let you update, as there will inevitably be other complications to deal with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution really is to update the TeX distribution. It will save headaches in the future, and the new `arrows.meta` library provides many nice features.

But, if upgrade is not an option: The conditional code below will check if the version of `pgf` loaded is 3.0.0 or later (dated on or after 2013/12/18). If yes, we load `arrows.meta` and `-Stealth` can be used as usual. If no, alias the arrow tip called `Stealth` to the old `stealth` tip provided by library `arrows`.

The end result of this is that `Stealth` will be used if TikZ/PGF 3.0.0 is available but fall back to `stealth` if they are not available, without any modifications to the drawing code.

**Limitations:** arrow style modifiers or other options (things like `-{Stealth[width=6pt]}`, for example) introduced with `arrows.meta` will not be successfully handled by this code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\usepackage{lmodern}        % fonts

\usepackage{tikz}           % provides TikZ
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{pgf}{2013/12/18}{
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
}{
  \pgfarrowsdeclarealias{Stealth}{Stealth}{stealth}{stealth}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-Stealth] (0,0) to (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work if there are arrow options?

Comment: @percusse: Unfortunately, no, I couldn't work that bit out (see the last sentence in my answer; I'll edit to make it stand out more).

Comment: My bad. I'm blind apparently.